# Cannot find reason why getting error "Error parsing XML: not well-formed(invalid token)"

Tags: android, xml

Getting the error: "Error parsing XML: not well-formed(invalid token)" supposedly caused by the Relative Layout not being properly closed with a '/>' or '>', however, I simply cannot find where the error occurs. Maybe I have been coding for too long today but hopefully someone with a fresh mind can spot it easily for me. Thank you.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/player_background">

    <!-- Player Header -->
    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/player_header_bg"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="60dip"
        android:background="@layout/bg_player_header"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:paddingLeft="5dp"
        android:paddingRight="5dp">

        <!-- Song Title -->
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/songTitle"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:textColor="#04b3d2"
            android:textSize="16dp"
            android:paddingLeft="10dp"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:text="The Good, The Bad And The Ugly"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"/>

        <!-- Playlist button -->
        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/btnPlaylist"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:src="@drawable/btn_playlist"
            android:background="@null"/>
    </LinearLayout>

    <!-- Song Thumbnail Image -->
    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/songThumbnail"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingTop="10dp"
        android:paddingBottom="10dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:layout_below="@id/player_header_bg">
        <ImageView android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@drawable/adele"/>
    </LinearLayout>

    <!-- Player Footer -->
    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/player_footer_bg"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:background="@layout/bg_player_footer"
        android:gravity="center">

        <!-- Player Buttons -->
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:gravity="center_vertical"
            android:background="@layout/rounded_corner"
            android:paddingLeft="10dp"
            android:paddingRight="10dp">
            <!-- Previous Button -->
            <ImageButton
                android:id="@+id/btnPrevious"
                android:src="@drawable/btn_previous"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="@null"/>
            <!-- Backward Button -->
            <ImageButton
                android:id="@+id/btnBackward"
                android:src="@drawable/btn_backward"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="@null"/>
            <!-- Play Button -->
            <ImageButton
                android:id="@+id/btnPlay"
                android:src="@drawable/btn_play"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="@null"/>
            <!-- Forward Button -->
            <ImageButton
                android:id="@+id/btnForward"
                android:src="@drawable/btn_forward"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="@null"/>
            <!-- Next Button -->
            <ImageButton
                android:id="@+id/btnNext"
                android:src="@drawable/btn_next"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="@null"/>
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>

    <!-- Progress Bar/Seek bar -->
    <SeekBar
         android:id="@+id/songProgressBar"
         android:layout_width="fill_parent"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
         android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
         android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
         android:layout_above="@id/player_footer_bg"
         android:thumb="@drawable/seek_handler"
         android:progressDrawable="@drawable/seekbar_progress"
         android:paddingLeft="6dp"
         android:paddingRight="6dp"/>

    <!-- Timer Display -->
    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/timerDisplay"
        android:layout_above="@id/songProgressBar"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp">
        <!-- Current Duration Label -->
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/songCurrentDurationLabel"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:gravity="left"
            android:textColor="#eeeeee"
            android:textStyle="bold"/>
        <!-- Total Duration Label -->
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/songTotalDurationLabel"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:gravity="right"
            android:textColor="#04cbde"
            android:textStyle="bold"/>
    </LinearLayout>

    <!-- Repeat / Shuffle buttons -->
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_above="@id/timerDisplay"
        android:gravity="center">
        <!-- Repeat Button -->
        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/btnRepeat"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@drawable/btn_repeat"
            android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
            android:background="@null"/>

        <!-- Shuffle Button -->
         <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/btnShuffle"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@drawable/btn_shuffle"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
            android:background="@null"/>
    </LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

SOLVED: Android SDK is very pedantic about the type of XML file you create in eclipse. Even though I deleted the default code, I had selected a non-layout XML file and this was the issue. Thanks for the answers though guys.

Comment: I didn't find any errors. Is the IDE acting up?

Comment: I have tried cleaning the project and restarting Eclipse but still getting these errors. Very strange.

Comment: getting no error in visual studio

Comment: Your XML checks out, as per Visual Studio.  Are you sure that one of your background XMLs isn't kicking something back?

Comment: I know it is weird, but to make this easier for others you might want to answer you own question and mark it as the right answer in 24 hours just so it is easier for people to see your solution.

Answer (score 0):

The XML file is valid and working for me.

There might be a problem with your IDE. Try to clean your project and rebuild it. To do that in Eclipse click on "Project" -> "Clean"

This solved a lot of XML parse errors for me in the past.